# Webhooks in Flask on Heroku

Tags: python, webhooks, telegram-bot

I have a flask app running on heroku: I am writing a telegram bot.

Given that I have already set the webhook url, what is the most effective way to handle the Updates requests? [Here](https://github.com/yukuku/telebot/blob/master/main.py) there is an example doing the same thing whith webapp2 on GAE. Is there an idiomatic way to do it on heroku with flask?